# How to insert text into a .txt file using form inputs?

Tags: php

I want a page where I can enter text into an input form, and then have that text inserted into a text file into the appropriate places.

For example, the input form will have 2 input form fields: 
1. how many pizzas?
2. which city?

It will update a text file that says:

There are **(1)**  pizzas in ***(2)***.

There are 5 pizzas in New York

Very simple, but how do I do this?

Comment: Why a text file? Isn't a database a better idea?

Comment: because I just need it for a very simple thing

Comment: isn't it simple to just type php files in google ?? ?? ??
3 seconds here you go http://goo.gl/w7Yyj

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('file.txt', 'There are ' . $_POST['pizzas'] . ' pizzas in ' . $_POST['city']);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="script.php" method="POST">
  Pizzas: <input type="text" name="pizzas"><br />
  City: <input type="text" name="city"><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: how do I access the text?   I put the php into script.php and created the HTML page, but when I submitted, nothing happened.

Comment: You should have file.txt on the server. If it's not there then you should check write permissions on the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON. It will let you edit the data easily (and because it's cool).

```
if ( empty( $_POST['pizzaCount'] ) === false && empty( $_POST['city'] ) === false )
{
   $savePath = 'folder/folder2/save.txt';
   $content = array();

   //does the file already exist?
   if ( ( $fileContents = file_get_contents( $savePath ) ) !== false )
   {
      //get the old data
      $content = json_decode( $fileContents , true );
   }
   //add the new data
   $content[] = array( 'pizzaCount' => $_POST['pizzaCount'] , 'city' => $_POST['city'] );

   //decode the new data
   $content = json_encode( $content );
   file_put_contents( $savePath , $content );

}
```

Comment: Is this php or javascript?  I don't know anything about coding.  I'm looking for code that I can literally copy paste.

Comment: It's PHP. You're not going to learn much with copy and paste, now, are you? But you can do that if you want. Just change the `$savePath` value to wherever you want to save the text file.